# Create a user form in Excel that uses formulas

Tags: excel, formula, userform

I have a simple excel file containing 2 tabs (Sheet1 and Sheet 2). Sheet 1 contains a list with multiple columns: file number (A), name (B), address(C), first_call (D), date/time of first call (E), second call (F), date/time of second call (G). Sheet2 is basically a form containing the same fields, built as follows:

```
A1 - file number (entered manually)
A2 - uses VLOOKUP to display name associated with the file number on A1 
A3 - uses VLOOKUP to display address associated with the file number on A1
A4 - drop down list containing several items (for instance, wrong number, not interested etc.)
A5 - time stamp, based on value in A4 (if an option is selected, A5 will show the date and time of selection and cannot be modified)
A6 - same as A4
A7 - same as A5
```

(In reality, the list is much larger, with more columns)

Now, admitting I enter a file number in A1. Information in A2 and A3 will be automatically displayed. I then select the result of the first phone call in A4. I want that selection (and the corresponding time stamp) to be carried to Sheet1, column D in the same line as the file number. This information should be permanent (like, if I enter the same file number again in Sheet2!A1, cell A4 should display the information previously entered). My only option at this point is to make another selection in Sheet2!A6.

I know how to create a user form, but the problem is that almost every cell in Sheet1 contains a formula. As a result, a simple user form is not an option.

Basically, I want my "form" in Sheet2 to be able to read from Sheet 1 or write to Sheet1 if the cell is blank. It's a 2-way form. If a cell in the list contains data, it will be displayed (read only). If not, it lets you update it.

I have also tried to use a 3rd sheet to kind of create a loop but it doesn't work.

I don't want somebody to do the work for me. I just want to know if this can be done with formulas (since my VBA knowledge is very, I mean very limited). Any help in this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Formulas are live and unless you want to manually copy/paste special the values you will need vba.

Comment: In case of VBA i'd say a properly written Worksheet_SelectionChange subroutine would do the work. With formulas... we might try but right now i don't see how...